# How does static_cast<type&&>(x) convert l valued r-value reference to x value type what is the internal logic?

Tags: c++, c++11

***I read std::move() does the same thing****

Comment: I'd have liked the addition of a unary `&&` to do what `std::move()` does.  *If I were king...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[expr.static.cast]/1** The result of the expression `static_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. If `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue; **if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue**; otherwise, the result is a prvalue.

Emphasis mine. Therefore, `static_cast<type&&>(x)`, where `type` is an object type (as opposed to a function type), is an xvalue by definition.